# ERROR: Could not find plugin "proposal-private-methods". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it

Tags: npm, babeljs, package.json

When trying to run `yarn dev` and I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\User\OtherFolders\src\index.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-private-methods". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it.
```

I have `"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "7.8.3"` as a dependency on my package.json file. Also, the @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods folder is present in the node_modules folder.

I had tried the following to no luck:

- Adding a resolution: `"@babel/compat-data": "7.10.1"` to the package file
  I remove the node_module folder, yarn-lock, and package-lock files before attempting to run `yarn install`. `yarn install` runs without issues
- I also try `$ npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods`

Any ideas on what the error could be or potential solutions? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to the Babel Project GitHub team to help to solve the issue. The issue solution is to change the version of @babel/preset-env from 7.8.6 to 7.8.7 or higher. The response to this ticket in GitHub is in this [link](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12019).